# Inline Visualforce in Lightning Community detail page

Tags: community, inline-visualforce, lightning-community

I have a inline visualforce page with a button and it works fine in Lightning.

But when I login as community user the inline vf pages appear but are no more Interactive(Cannot click on button or any functionality in that vf page). It just appears as an image in the detail page. Initially I thought its my page but when i tried to add different types of vf pages even with a basic functionality it appears as an image.

Is it a limitation or is there any workaround Please Advice.

Answer (score 3):

Looks similar to this [Known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001Ch4QAE).

Below workaround might help. 
Add below CSS to Community branding custom CSS.

```
.oneAlohaPage .mask { 
display: none; 
}
```